# Entanglement in 2D Harmonic Oscillator system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-entanglement

Let's assume a 2 dimensional harmonic oscillator system with the Hamiltonian $\hat{H} = \frac{1}{2} p_x^2 + \frac{1}{2} p_y^2 + \frac{1}{2} \omega_x^2 x^2 + \frac{1}{2} \omega_y^2 y^2$ with the solution of the ground state being simply the product of the the ground state of each independent mode.

$\psi_{gs}(x,y) = \psi_{x}(x) \psi_{y}(y) \propto e^{-w_xx^2} e^{-w_yy^2} $ which is clearly a separable solution.

But when we rotate our coordinate system by $\pi/4$ we, get the new coordinates to be
$ x' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x + y)$ and $y' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x - y) $

and expressing the solution in those coordinates will lead to the solution
$\psi_{gs}(x',y') \neq \psi_{x'}(x') \psi_{y'}(y') $ and hence a signature of entanglement.

How can rotating a physical system (or just someone choosing a different coordinate system) lead to it being entangled?

Answer (score 1):

Entanglement means the system not separable in *any* basis (or coordinate system).  It’s not always easy to show there is no transformation (such as the inverse of the one you propose) that would bring a system to an explicitly separable form.

The development of practical *[entanglement witnesses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_witness)* to show entanglement irrespective of the coordinate system or basis is still an active area of research.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @ZeroTheHero answer: one usually talks about entanglement in a narrower sense, as a state of two or more particles, since what we have here can be described as a superposition of one-particle states (whatever is the basis).

Comment: Correct, although you could think of a 2d h.o. as a pair of 1d harmonic oscillators.